# ASP Core WebAPI For Multiple Sites, Saving Data To Different Databases

Tags: angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am the web developer at a company that creates web applications for multiple clients. I was wondering if it is possible to create a web API that targets n number of databases. What I mean by this is, basically all sites will have similar fields containing data, give or take a couple fields.

For the Front-End I am using Angular 5 and above taking form information and posting the data to the database. I am using ASP Core for the back end processing.

If I have three individual sites needing to post data to three different databases, can I use a single instance of ASP Core Web API to process the form data and save, by using different connection strings and Entity Framework. From the Angular UI, I would make a post request with the form information and a given ID and based on the ID get the correct DB_Context with the correct connection string and process the data.

I was thinking of doing it this way, otherwise I would have to make a separate Web Api for each site.

Comment: If the business purpose of the application is same, I don't think there will be vast changes with different clients. Single API will be ok, but you need to maintain the proper documentation for API. Also, the fields which are required vs non-required needs to be identified, how to identify the request of a customer, etc. Things like this needs to be sorted out before hand inorder to avoid maintenance hassles later.

Comment: Front end should be "feature driven" approach so you can turn on/off for a customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical limitation for your request. You can use as many databases as you need in your application.

In the Data Access Layer of your backend, you would need to create several DbContext, one for each database you would like to use.
Those DbContexts will be used by your repositories, those repo would be used by your services, and those services would be used by your controllers (for instance).

Your just need to link the right endpoints with the right DbContexts, in order to get the relevant data.

Here is an article on how to work with several DbContexts in one application : https://hackingmonkeys.com/blog/2018-03-24/ef-core-multiple-db-contexts-schemas-and-projects

**However**, keep in mind that your API is going to change, to grow, and it is going to be hard to maintain. It is possible that you will spend more time on making the three APIs work together than the required time to develop three separated applications.